# How to get the list of bonded bluetooth devices in a friendly name

Tags: android, bluetooth, friendly-id

I am trying to get the list of the bonded bluetooth devices on the phone.
My problem is that I am getting it in a "non friendly" way.
Here is my code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList<String> listview = 
        new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(pairedDevices.toString()));
```

I'm getting: `00:23:7f:5f:fe:1c...`

How can i get the friendly names and not numbers?

Just to add that I know about `getname()`, but as I understand its only for a connected device and not for the bonded devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `getName()` method of the `BluetoothDevice` device class will help you out. Just iterate through the `Set` and call the `getName()` method on each `BluetoothDevice` object.